# iOS: ASIHTTPRequest validate self sign certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, asihttprequest, self-signed

With library [asi-http-request](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) and I have imported a certificate (.der) into resource bundle and want to make https connection only to server which providing the self sign certificate.

How can I achive this? I don't want to just disabling `setValidatesSecureCertificate` and allowing all https connections.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [patch](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/pull/314), asi-http-request able to trust a customized trust store.